# understanding coredns config yaml

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I'm very new to kubernetes, and I'm tasked to continue project which was started by someone else. I just want to understand the what the following code does to the kubernetes, especially corefile part. thank you.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
            ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . 8.8.8.8
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

Comment: Corefile is the configuration file for the CoreDNS service in Kubernetes. The configuration specifies how CoreDNS should behave, and includes settings such as errors, health checks, Kubernetes service discovery, Prometheus metrics endpoint, DNS forwarding, caching, loop prevention, and load balancing.

Answer (score 1):

The Corefile part is the configuration for your cluster's CoreDNS deployment. It's wrapped in a `ConfigMap` so that you can manage it like any other Kubernetes resource.

CoreDNS is a DNS server. Your Kubernetes cluster needs a local DNS server so that your pods, services, etc. can discover each other by name.

Most important:
any DNS request that can't be resolved in the local environment will be forwarded to the IP you specify at "forward . [remote DNS]"

See https://coredns.io/manual/configuration/